# Matrix definition order and memory order not same

Tags: c, memory, matrix

When defining 4 matrices I was sure they would end up in the same order in memory, however...

```
include <stdio.h>
define ROWCOUNT (3)
define COLUMNCOUNT (4)

int imat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ]; 
char cmat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
double dmat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
int rmat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
```

This is the code I used, and this is the addresses of the different matrices:
locating the first element in every matrix

```
Examining imat: memory at: 1004061c0
Examining cmat: memory at: 1004062a0
Examining dmat: memory at: 100406240
Examining rmat: memory at: 100406200
```

Well I may just be blind but to me it looks like that they lie in the order i-r-d-c, and that(even reversed) isn't the same as the definition order. Why do they end up in the wrong order in memory?

thx for help :)

Comment: Are you sure this is your code (no `#` in preprocessors)?

Comment: Why would you assume any specific ordering between them? Are they members of a struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely reason is that these arrays have different sizes (cmat is 12 bytes, dmat probably 96 bytes) and the compiler rearranges them to fit some alignment requirements. A common technique is to place objects with the strictest alignment requirements first (ints, doubles), and those with the least requirements (like array-of-char) last. This way the wasted memory due to *padding* is minimized.

But then, why do you care about the sequence of different objects in memory? If you want to force a sequence, put them in the same struct (struct members must appear in the sequence of their declaration).

Comment: Got to answer a question in a school project. My teacher has hubris.

Answer (score 1):

Contigous memory allocation is done for structs members. In your case the arrays are declared in a function, so it is not necessary they will be assigned contigous memory locations.

***Here is the example code:***

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROWCOUNT 3
#define COLUMNCOUNT 4

struct test{
    int imat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
    char cmat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
    double dmat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
    int rmat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
};

int main(void)
{
   struct test obj;

    int imat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
    char cmat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
    double dmat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];
    int rmat[ ROWCOUNT ][ COLUMNCOUNT ];

    printf("\n Main Arrays\n");    
    printf(" %p\n %p\n %p \n%p\n  ", (void*) imat, (void*) cmat, (void*) dmat, (void*) rmat);
    printf("\n Structure Arrays\n");
    printf(" %p\n %p\n %p\n %p\n  ", (void*) obj.imat, (void*) obj.cmat, (void*) obj.dmat, (void*) obj.rmat);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to rephrase that a bit: allocation in structs may be non-contiguous as well, although members are ordered.

Comment: @chill As far as I know it will be true if there are some other declarations between arrays or compiler assigns them non contiguous address for optimization purposes.

Comment: ... or simply padding and alignment :)

Comment: You *must* cast the `%p` arguments to `void *`; without them it is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Jens done. Thanks for pointing that out, Almost forgot that :)

Answer (score 0):

Contiguous memory allocation done in case of array and structures for their elements and not for different arrays and structures. In other cases, including yours, no guarantee for contiguous memory allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Placement of global variables depends on your compilation tools and target enviroment. Usually you don't have to care about it, and can let the tools do the right thing.

Tools might have some features to control placement, but are not portable, and should be used only if really needed.

Answer (score 0):

> Why do they end up in the wrong order in memory?

How do you define what order is right and what is wrong? **The compiler is free to rearrange virtually any variable declaration**, with some optimizations turned on it can even skip a variable altogether. You shouldn't make any assumptions to in what order given variables are allocated in memory - and you shouldn't *need* to make any.